# Tamaño de los archivos de la base de datos, log y temp SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hola estuve investigando como saber el tamaño (bytes o kilobytes) a los archivos asociado a una base de datos (data, log y temp), para luego insertar información y ver cuanto subió el tamaño de cada archivo,  estos archivos si no me equivoco esta en la ruta C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA ojala alguno de ustedes me lo pueda confirmar, ademas si existe algún método para obtener esta información para poder realizar un calculo de cuando pesara estos archivos en un año.

Ojala me puedan ayudar se le agradecería mucho.

Atento a sus comentarios :)

Answer (score 2):

Una base de datos puede componerse de múltiples archivos (datos y log), la ubicación de estos archivos, dependerá de la configuración inicial, es posible que la carpeta default sea la que menciones, pero en realidad se pueden ubicar en cualquier path. Una forma rápida y cómoda de ver estos archivos, es mediante [`sp_helpfile()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helpfile-transact-sql), en una ventana de transact-sql, debemos primero situarnos en la base a ver, por ejemplo:

```
USE master
GO
EXEC sp_helpfile
```

Y un ejemplo de la salida:

```
+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+-----------+
| name    | fileid | filename                                                                         | filegroup | size      | maxsize       | growth   | usage     |
+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+-----------+
| master  | 1,00   | C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf  | PRIMARY   | 106496 KB | Unlimited     | 10240 KB | data only |
+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+-----------+
| mastlog | 2,00   | C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf |           | 594944 KB | 2147483648 KB | 10240 KB | log only  |
+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+-----------+
```

En la columna `size` tendrás el tamaño actual del archivo asociado al database.

Comment: muchas gracias Patricio me sirvió mucho tu respuesta